# Deserialize complex JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json.net

I am working on a C# app that fetches data from an API. The response from the API has blocks that contain a node `Data` that changes in structure and only shares one attribute, `Type`. I am using Newtonsoft. How can I deserialize the `Data` node to the exact class based on the `Type` attribute? So that if I create an items array, when I query the array I can switch on the `Type` attribute and know which object maps to it.

The JSON response from the API looks like this:

```
{
    "nextLink": "NextLink",
    "value": [
        {
            "Block": {
                "BlockName": "Name",
                "BlockClass": "Class",
                "IsVisibile": true,
                "Data": {
                    "Type": "Footer",
                    "Values": [
                        { 
                            "Property1": "Property1",
                            "Property2": "Property2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Show": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Block": {
                "BlockName": "Name",
                "BlockClass": "Class",
                "IsVisibile": true,
                "Data": {
                    "Type": "Header",
                    "Title": "Main title",
                    "Subtitle": "Subtitle"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Block": {
                "BlockName": "Name",
                "BlockClass": "Class",
                "IsVisibile": true,
                "Data": {
                    "Type": "Body",
                    "Information": "Info",
                    "AdditionalText": "More text",
                    "Projects": [
                        "Project1",
                        "Project2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

These are the classes I have defined based on the API response:

```
public class Blocks
{
    public string NextLink { get; set; }
    public Response[] Value { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Block Block { get; set; }
}

public class Block
{
    public string BlockName { get; set; }
    public string BlockClass { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    ???
}

public class FooterType
{
    public bool Show { get; set; }
    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class HeaderType 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class BodyType
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalText { get; set; }
    public object[] Projects { get; set; }
}
```

If I deserialize the response to the specific Type (like below) it of course works for that node in the JSON but not all of them.

```
public class Data 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize each item in the JSON to the specific type it maps to?

Comment: What you are looking for is called _Polymorphic Serialization & Deserialization_. You can do it (how depends on the serializer - and the version). Apparently, the latest System.Text.Json does this out of the box. Getting it to work can be frustrating

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57. I read about `System.Text.Json` but unfortunately it's only available in .Net7 and I'm using .Net6. Either way I was able to get it working with the solutions below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to create the polymorphic clases and use a json property constructor

```
    Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

public class Root
{
    public string nextLink { get; set; }
    public List<Item> value { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public Block Block { get; set; }
}
public class Block
{
    public string BlockName { get; set; }
    public string BlockClass { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisibile { get; set; }
    public DataBase Data { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Block (JObject Data)
    {
        this.Data = (DataBase)Data.ToObject(Type.GetType((string)Data["Type"]));
    }
    public Block() {}
}

public class DataBase
{
    public string Type { get; set;}
    //public string Type { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
}

public class Footer : DataBase
{
    public List<Properties> Values { get; set; }
    public bool Show { get; set; }
}

public class Header : DataBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class Body : DataBase
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalText { get; set; }
    public List<string> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

but if you have a lot of json of this kind, instead of adding one line to a constructor you can create a json property converter

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

public class DataPropertyConverter : JsonConverter<DataBase>
{
    public override DataBase ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DataBase existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
         return (DataBase)jObj.ToObject(Type.GetType((string)jObj["Type"]));
    }
    
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DataBase value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Block
{
    public string BlockName { get; set; }
    public string BlockClass { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisibile { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DataPropertyConverter))]
    public DataBase Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get it working this way with the caveat that the API doesn't return the full namespace, which `Type.GetType()` needs. I hacked a way for it to work with your solution and @Martin's in case I find issues with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by writing your own converter which is doing the class selection

> This example is using Newtonsoft as De/serialization libary. [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

```cs
public class DataConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(Data).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); 

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            // Read the target Type from the json data object
            var dataType = (string)obj["Type"];
            var item = new Data();
            // Determine what is the correct sub class for your data
            switch(dataType)
            {
                case "Header": 
                    item = new HeaderType();
                    break;
                case "Body": 
                    item = new BodyType();
                    break;
                case "Footer": 
                    item = new FooterType();
                    break;
            }
            // Populate the instance with the data provided in json
            serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), item);
            return item;
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

Here is the working example for your case [in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HWtQLr)

```cs
// Then just use it in your ´JsonConvert.DeserializeObject´ method
var blocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Blocks>(json, new DataConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I ended up combining your solution and Serge's.